# In my controller I have function named "chiliClick". Why is it not invoking?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, ng-controller

I have two functions with same name "chiliClick". The uncommented function is not invoking even after hitting the button chili nor is it throwing any error in console.  However the same function (commented) working fine with same code. Is there any difference? Please help

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  var clickController = function($scope){

    $scope.spicy = 'very';

    function chiliClick(){
      $scope.spicy = 'chili';  
    }

    // $scope.chiliClick = function(){
    //   $scope.spicy = 'chili'; 
    // }

  };

  app.controller("clickController", clickController);

}());// Code goes here
```

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Controller </title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div ng-controller="clickController">
       <button ng-click="chiliClick()">Chili</button>
       <button>jalapeño</button>
       <p> this is {{spicy}} hot <p>
    </div>


     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="myApp.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

What are the differences between the declarations of function "chiliClick"?

Comment: BTW you should write your IIFE as `(function(){...})();` and not `(function(){...}());`. In that form I'm not sure it's doing its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one creates a local function.

```
function chiliClick(){
    $scope.spicy = 'chili';  
}
```

What that means is that it's essentially a local object in the scope of your controller.  You'd be able to call it in that scope, but you never do.  You can think of this as conceptually similar to a `private` function in other languages.

The second one creates a function as a property of the `$scope` object.

```
$scope.chiliClick = function(){
   $scope.spicy = 'chili'; 
}
```

*This* time, you've attached the function to something that angular will let you call (the `$scope` object).  You can think of this as similar to a `public` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's really helpful in understanding @Ian McLaird

Answer (score 0):

Yes! there's a big difference.

Because in your commented function you wrote:

```
$scope.chiliClick = ...
```

When doing this, you provide your function to the scope, so your HTML knows about the `chiliClick` function.

but when you just do as in the uncommented one, your HTML doesn't know anything about the function (since it is local variable, declared inside your controller function).